# Dimension and basis of a vectorial subspace of the polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $F_a=\{p(x)\in E | p(a) = 0\}$, a subspace of $E=\{p(x)\in R[x] | deg(p(x)) \le 2\}$, I'm asked to find the dimension and a basis of Fa. How can I start?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

If $\;V\;$ is a vector space of a field $\;\Bbb F\;$ and $\;\dim V=n\;$ , and if $\phi:V\to \Bbb F\;,\;\;\phi\neq 0\;$ , is a linear functional , then

$$\dim\ker\phi=n-1$$

(hint for the proof: use the rank-nullity theorem, also known as the dimensions theorem)

Comment: What I understand is that you are identifying $ker \phi$ with $F_a$, which means that the vectors of $ker \phi$ belong to $F_a$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes @Allonsy...what is $\;\phi\;$ **exactly**, then?

Comment: It's the polynomial. So you're identifying each polynomial with a function that you call it linear functional. Truth is that we don't know anything about linear functionals yet haha.

Comment: No, it's not "the polynomial" but what is called the evaluation homomorphism (or linear transformation): $$\phi(p(x)):=p(a)$$. A linear functional is only a linear tranformation which image is inte hdefinition field.

Comment: I'd like to see you back, @DonAntonio! ;-)